# Linux command line - search a file inside a tar archive

Tags: linux, tar

I would like to check whether a file is in a gzip'ed tar archive.
For example I want to check whether the /etc/passwd is present in the archive backup_2010-09-27.tar.gz

A dumb solution can be:

```
tar -tzf backup_2010-09-27.tar.gz | grep '/etc/passwd'
```

But that takes time. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this (omit the initial slash):

```
tar -tzf backup_2010-09-27.tar.gz etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 1):

its gunzipping process that eats time and there's no way to reach the tar archive members before gunzipping. I don't know how much will help to explicitly specify a member offset when listing the tar but if the member lookup process is faster than fully listing then:

```
tar -K etc/passwd -tzf backup_2010-09-27.tar.gz| head -1
```

i doubt it tho.

you can also try to extract the file and check the return code so you will get rid of fully listing the archive and grepping afterwise.

```
echo etc/passwd | tar -T - -K etc/passwd -Oxzf backup_2010-09-27.tar.gz >/dev/null
```

$? should be zero

still, gunzipping ....